# How to get 24 hour time format in gmt+6

Tags: php

I am staying now in a place on time under gmt+6

I want to see my time in 24 hour time format. I wrote the code :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+6');

echo $date2=date("H:i:s");
```

But it shows time in 12 hour format like time is: `10:02:00`.

but whet I write only the following line

```
echo $date2=date("H:i:s");
```

It shows me time in 12 hour format but always take 4 hour less . i.e it should show `22:02:00` but it shows `18:02:00`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what returns `date_default_timezone_get()` in the latter case?

Comment: I believe you may want to look into `gmdate` http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timezone  = +6; //(GMT +6:00) 
echo gmdate("H:i:s", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
```